# Closing Download Tabs in Selenium with Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am automating some data download. After selecting a bunch of files to download, a new tab opens up in the Chromedriver to begin the download. What I want to do is shut down this tab once the download is completed. However, I am not having any success using the send_keys functionality. I tried messing around with the window_handles approach...but that did not seem to work either.

```
for i in listofpa:
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(i).click()

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mainContentRight > div.pagination > ul > li:nth-child(13) > a').click()

except:
    pass

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("tsMore").click()

try:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#saveExportLink_6').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@id,"deselectCheckBox_")]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id,"submitButton")]').click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.find_element_by_id("progressZone").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')

except:

    pass
```

Comment: iirc `send_keys()` will send the keys sequentially. This is probably why your approach is not working. Also its sending the keys directly to the page, not the application, so even if you were to come up with a way to send simultaneously it wouldn't work. Personally, I would use selenium to navigate to the page to get the URL of the download, and then use `urllib` to actually do the downloading.

Comment: Normally I would too...but in order to launch the download you have to click a button which launches a javascript based window to configure the download. There is no direct download link...